# SQL join what is wrong here?

Tags: php, sql, join, inner-join

I have this code and I can not find the error, something for me?

```
     $idea = $bdd->query("SELECT ideas.id, ideas.titulo, ideas.descripcion,
     ideas.idcreador, ideas.likes, ideas.dislike, ideas.fechacreacion, ideas.comunidad,
     ideas.tag, follow.idaseguir, follow.idseguidor, follow.estado
     FROM ideas LEFT OUTER JOIN follow ON ideas.idcreador=follow.idseguidor
 WHERE follow.idseguidor ='".$_SESSION['userid']."' ORDER BY id DESC");         
                while($datoideaperfil2 = $idea->fetch())
                {
                    echo $datoideaperfil2['idseguidor'];        
                }
```

I now is not very clean, sorry about that.

Edit: Just cleaner formatting of the SQL query being used above:

```
SELECT 
    ideas.id, 
    ideas.titulo, 
    ideas.descripcion,
    ideas.idcreador, 
    ideas.likes, 
    ideas.dislike, 
    ideas.fechacreacion, 
    ideas.comunidad,
    ideas.tag, 
    follow.idaseguir, 
    follow.idseguidor, 
    follow.estado
FROM 
    ideas 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN follow 
            ON ideas.idcreador=follow.idseguidor
WHERE 
    follow.idseguidor ='".$_SESSION['userid']."' 
ORDER BY 
    id DESC
```

Comment: Didn't I just answer this a moment ago and say that you had two columns called ID in your tables, which means you need to be specific about which one to order by in the `order by tablename.id` section of your code.

Comment: yes more question = answers thank you. but still not working

Comment: Okay, so when you echo out the `session` variable that you use in the sql, what do you get?

Comment: Apart from either the variable being empty when you try to use it, or the same issue where you have a column called id in both tables (leading to an ambigous order by statement), the only thing that I can think of is that you have either a typo in your column or table names.

Comment: What error or unexpected result are you getting? (Btw, rather than reformatting queries here - although that is appreciated - why not store the query in your code in that nicely formatted way? PHP completely allows it).

Answer (score 0):

i think follow.idseguidor is int field so you can do as follow.

```
SELECT 
ideas.id, 
ideas.titulo, 
ideas.descripcion,
ideas.idcreador, 
ideas.likes, 
ideas.dislike, 
ideas.fechacreacion, 
ideas.comunidad,
ideas.tag, 
follow.idaseguir, 
follow.idseguidor, 
follow.estado
FROM 
ideas 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN follow 
        ON ideas.idcreador=follow.idseguidor
WHERE 
follow.idseguidor ={$_SESSION['userid']} 
ORDER BY 
id DESC
```